# After closing div refresh another div

Tags: javascript

I am using js function to hide div

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="closediv">You have deleted an item!</div>

<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#closediv').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 5000
);
</script>
```

I am using this function to close information that prints in a div. Once the information is closed, I would like to refresh another div or whole page

Div I want to refresh is

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#closediv').fadeOut('slow');
       }, 5000
       $('#mainContent').location.reload();
       );                   
    }
</script>
```

Script does not work once I added to refresh div: Any help is appreciated, I need to close div first then refresh another div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just do that in the completion handler of `fadeOut()`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#closediv').fadeOut('slow',function(){
      location.reload()
  });
}, 5000);
```

If you're facing any problems with confirmation, using `location.href = location.href` instead of `location.reload()` should help.

Comment: It does not work. I have tried it does not close link and refresh page

Comment: @user Probably you had a typo, see the updated code.

Comment: It is good now, is it possible to refresh without confirming to refresh page

Comment: I have added window.location.href = window.location.href; thanks it works great now